# Problem on Lagrange multiplier (gradient method )

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Find extrema (local or global) point(s) of a function subject to the given constraint
$$f(x, y) = x^2 + 4y^2 − 2x + 8y, x + 2y = 7.$$ Use Lagrange multiplier  (gradient method).

Let the Lagrange multiplier be $$L(x,y,\lambda)=f(x, y)-\lambda g(x,y)$$
where $g(x,y)=x+2y-7.$

Then $\nabla L=0$ implies $\nabla f=\lambda \nabla g$, and $g(x,y)=0$.

We then get the system of equations $2x-2=\lambda, 4y+4=\lambda, x+2y=7$. Solving we get the stationary point as $(x,y)=(5,1)$.

**Q1: How to check that there is a minimum at $(5,1)$?**

**Q2: How to check whether the extremum point is local or global extremum?**

Comment: In this case, it is easy to substitute $x=7-2y$ and reduce to a function of one variable, which makes it clear that this is an absolute minimum.

Comment: True, but as it is mentioned that one has to use Lagrange multiplier (gradient method), then ---- write f to one variable and differentiate it--- this process of finding max/min is not looking to be appropriate.

Comment: Is there any alternate way to check

Comment: It's clear there is no max.  Completing the squares gives $(x-1)^2+4(y+1)^2-5$  (I did it in my head, so I might have the constant wrong, but that doesn't matter).  The function goes to infinity as $|x|, |y|$ get big.

Comment: Check the Bordered Hessian method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix